# Is it possible to email the contents of vim using HTML

Tags: html, email, vim, diff

I like to view the current differences in the source files I'm working on with a command like:

```
vim <(svn diff -dub)
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is to email that colorized diff.  I know vim can export HTML with the :TOhtml, but how do I pipeline this output into an html email?  Ideally. i'd like to be able to send an html diff with a single shell script command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following one-liner produces an HTML file named `email.html`:

```
diff file1 file2 | vim - +TOhtml '+w email.html' '+qall!'
```

You can now use Pekka’s code to send the email.

**However**, I believe in using the right tool for the right job – and VIM may not be the right tool here. Other highlighters exist and their use is more appropriate here.

For example, [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) can be harnessed to produce the same result, much more efficiently and hassle-free:

```
diff -u report.log .report.log | pygmentize -l diff -f html > email.html
```

Notice that this produces *only* the actual text body, not the style sheet, nor the surrounding HTML scaffold. This must be added separately but that’s not difficult either. Here’s a complete bash script to produce a valid minimal HTML file:

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>No title</title><style>' > email.html
pygmentize -S default -f html >> email.html
echo '</style></head><body>' >> email.html 
diff -u report.log .report.log | pygmentize -l diff -f html >> email.html 
echo '</body></html>' >> email.html
```

**EDIT** In case that Pekka’s code didn’t work – as for me – because you don’t have the required versions of `mail` and `mutt` installed then you can use `sendmail` as follows to send the HTML email:

```
( echo 'To: email-address@example.com'
  echo 'Content-Type: text/html'
  echo 'Subject: test'
  echo ''
  cat email.html ) | sendmail -t
```

It’s important to leave an empty line between the header and the body of the email. Also, notice that it’s of course unnecessary to create the temporary file `email.html`. Just paste the rest of the commands into the right place above and delete the redirects to file.

Comment: you have an interesting definition of "more efficiently and hassle-free".  +1 for how to get vim to write and quit from the command line.

Comment: you could change the "+w email.html" to `+%!mutt` or whatever to have vim invoke the mail command directly

Comment: @rampion: Launching Vim that way is actually quite inefficient. Pygments easily outperforms it. By hassle-free I simply mean that the Pygments work-flow is conceptually easier (“syntax-highlight a diff”, as opposed to “open a diff in an editor, run a command, close editor”) even though it’s more text to write. Both methods have their merits I think.

Comment: +1 I agree with the fact that vim is not the adequate tool in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Linux Guru, but this looks like it should serve your needs to pipe your output into:

[Send an HTML file as email from the command line.](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Send_an_HTML_file_as_email_from_the_command_line.) (uses `mail`)

There's also a one-line `mutt` example [here](http://does-not-exist.org/mail-archives/mutt-users/msg07771.html):

```
mutt -e "my_hdr Content-Type: text/html" 
     -s "my subject" you@xxxxxxxxxxx < message.html
```

this will generate a pure HTML E-Mail with no pure text alternative - for that you would have to build multi-part mail... But maybe it'll do for what you need.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Is there something technically wrong here?